# What is the significance of the recording played during the coffin scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, house-of-1000-corpses

In *House of 1000 Corpses* (2003), one of the final scenes is the firefly clan making Denise and Jerry get into a coffin, which they then lower into a pit.

Otis has a tape recorder that he starts playing that sounds like an incantation of sorts, and it's lowered into the pit as well. What is this recording and what is it's significance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to IMDB http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0251736/trivia?item=tr0766954 it is one line from Aleister Crowley's poem "The Poet" (as recorded by Crowley himself) repeated over and over (and also slowed down). The line is "Bury me in a nameless grave"

In Captain Spaulding's establishment, there are reproductions of some of Crowley's paintings as well.

As for the significance, it's hard to say. Crowley had a strange sense of humor (for example, he referred to masturbation as "human sacrifice") and many of his writings can be taken in a variety of ways. He is often linked with satanism, though I believe that had more do with the fact that he was an anti-christian, occultist drug addict that was openly promiscuous and called himself "the Beast," all in the early 1900s. My guess is that Rob Zombie just thought it sounded creepy as hell and it worked in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

The line is "bury me in a nameless grave," so match it against the context of the scene.  Essentially, two victims have had their identities stripped away, called rabbits, and will disappear forever.  Nobody will ever truly know what happened to either of them.  Think about the scene before this one, where one of the rabbits ended up getting stabbed to death in a cemetery of nameless graves, too.  Once they're lowered into the "grave," actually a labyrinth, Denise runs into an old man in a rabbit costume.  She's potentially looking at her 'future,' wandering around in the dark without any sense of identity.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

It's "Bury me in a nameless grave, I came from god, the world to save."

Comment: And it's significance. You probably answered half the question